# Need help in click function in jquery

Tags: jquery, click

I have a widget in my page. If i click on any part of the widget it should navigate to next page which has some details about that widget. I need a dialog to be opened if i click on a span named "likes" available within that widget. But instead it is navigating to the next page even if i click on that link..

It should navigate to next page if i click on any part of the widget except that link..

This is normal code for click:

```
 $('td#' + parentElement).find('div.streamcontenttopmain').click(function() {
            window.location.href = 'TaskDetails.aspx?id=' + json_row.id + '&community=' + getQueryParam('community');
        });
```

This code will it navigate to next page if i click anywhere within the widget

My span is defined like this:

```
<span class="flft likes" style="MARGIN-LEFT: 2px">
```

This is What i tried:

```
 $('td#' + parentElement).find('div.streamcontenttopmain').click(function (e) {

            if ($(this).hasClass("flft likes")) {

                alert("hi");
            } else {
                window.location.href = 'TaskDetails.aspx?id=' +
                               json_row.id +
                               '&community=' +
                               getQueryParam('community');
            }
        });
```

Comment: I posted an answer using the condition. The problem is that even when you click the span the event won't be handled until it's propagated to the 'div.streamcontenttopmain'` element at which point `this`will be the div and not the span

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop the event from bubbling up to the `div` elements and triggering their event handlers:

```
$('#' + parentElement).find('span.likes').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you stop the propagation of the event you can handle it in the span wihtout it ever reaching the div. That woul look similar to the below

```
$('td#' + parentElement).find('div.streamcontenttopmain').click(function(e){
      window.location.href = 'TaskDetails.aspx?id=' + 
                               json_row.id + 
                               '&community=' + 
                               getQueryParam('community');
})).find('span.likes').click(function(e) {
           e.stopPropagation();
           //do the span specific stuff here
});
```

Comment: I have edited my question in the way u mentioned.. I have tried in the same way but still it remains the same..

Should i add anything more...

Comment: @Xavier the original answer I wrote was a blunder (see comment to question for why) this which expands on Blenders answer will however work if I've understood your question and context correct

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').click(function(e){
        if(e.toElement.nodeName == "SPAN")
            alert('span clicked');
        else
            alert('div clicked');
    });
});
```

I showed it in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SxhWy/3/

Comment: I have tried the way u mentioned.. But it is throwing an exception as:
"console is undefined"

Comment: @Xavier I deleted this line, It was only needed for me to trace the exact names of fields.

Comment: @RuneFS I will try to be more explicit.